# The current path, {% url 'post_detail' post.pk % }, didn’t match any of these error in django

Tags: python, django

[hi i am new to django and i am facing a problem when using primary keys.project name is blog project and app is blog this is my code.]
this is the screenshot of the error when i click on a heading:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWgDv.png)

```
#blog/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import BlogListView,BlogDetailView
urlpatterns = [
    path("post/<int:pk>/",BlogDetailView.as_view(),name = "post_detail"),
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name = "home"),
    
   
]
#blog/templates/home.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<style>
    .post-entry{ 
        color:antiquewhite;

    }
</style>

{% block content %}  
{% for post in object_list %}  
<div class = "post-entry">
    <h2><a  href = "{% url 'post_detail' post.pk  % }">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>

</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
#views.py
 from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "home.html"
class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"
```

Comment: "{% url 'post_detail/' post.pk  % }" -> "{% url 'post_detail' post.pk  %}"

Comment: it was no use same error i got again

Comment: If the `Request URL` in the screenshot does not change, your template file is not properly updated in the browser.

Comment: I wish I could see screenshots after editing.

Comment: Share your views.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### A Solution to try

I agree with gyspark's comment, but I also think `post.pk` needs to be changed to `post.id`. For example:

**blog/templates/home.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<style>
    .post-entry{ 
        color:antiquewhite;

    }
</style>

{% block content %}  
{% for post in object_list %}  
<div class = "post-entry">
    <h2><a  href="{% url "post_detail" post.id  %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>

</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**blog/urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import BlogListView, BlogDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/", BlogDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
]
```

But also, are you importing blog.urls into the main app's urls.py file? Or is the main app called "blog"?

---

#### Other tips

Another thing that could be useful is to add a style block to **base.html**:

```html
<!-- The rest of your code -->
<style>
{% block style %} 
{% endblock %} 
</style>
</head>

<!-- the rest of your code -->
```

and then in your templates, like **home.html**, you would update it like so:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block style %}
    .post-entry{ 
        color:antiquewhite;

    }
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}  
{% for post in object_list %}  
<div class = "post-entry">
    <h2><a  href="{% url "post_detail" post.id  % }">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>

</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It's a spelling error because it's not rendering "`{% %}`" at all, just taking it as a string value.

Comment: changed .pk to .id and '' to "" then it worked thank you

Comment: @YatinLakkaraju Not sure how changing `post.pk` to `post.id` solved your problem.

Comment: [NixonSparrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12775662/nixonsparrow), if you are referring to the URL, it has never not worked for me but I see why you'd think that. 

[Yatin Lakkaraju](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17418207/yatin-lakkaraju), No problem! I'm glad it worked out.

Comment: i dont know exactly but changed 'post.pk' to "post.id" the problem solved

Comment: As we can see from the screenshot you provided, there is a typo when using the built-in template tag `url`. I think replacing `.pk` to `.id` in the information provided by the questioner is over-debugging.

Answer (score -1):

You have a spelling error:

```
"{% url 'post_detail/' post.pk  % }"
```

Delete `/` and extra space in closing `%}`:

```
"{% url 'post_detail' post.pk  %}"
```